# How can I automatically load all data sets from my own package

Tags: r, package, dataset

Assume I have two packages

- `package1`

  - data sets d1, d2, d3
- `package2` which should use data sets from `package1`

`package1` contains data sets, which I want to use for testing.
I can access each of these via e.g. `package1::d1`. But how can I load all of them in an automated way?

Something like

```
ds <- data(package = "package1") # you can try e.g. "carData"
ds$results[1, 3] # gives the first entry
mydataset <- load(ds$results[1, 3]) # this does not work
```

Other will use both packages, so it should work for others and on different platforms (Windows, Mac)
Any ideas?

---

```
ds$results[1, 3]
#  Item 
#  "d1"
```

looks promising, but

```
data(ds$results[1, 3])
# Warning message:
# In data(ds$results[1, 3]) : data set ‘ds$results[1, 3]’ not found
```

Comment: Does `data(ds$results[1, 3])` do what you want? To load them all `data(list=ds$results[, 3])`.

Comment: @dcarlson No, although `ds$results[1, 3]` looks good. See my edit (does not fit in a comment). No data set is loaded.

Comment: This is working for me: `ds <- data(package="carData"); data(list=ds$results[1, 3], package="carData"); ls()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just realized, there are two options:

You want to load external files from `inst/extdata`

```
pathExtData <- system.file("extdata", package = "myPackage")
allFilenames <- list.files(pathExtData, full.names = TRUE)
# e.g. in case of Excel files
datalist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(allFilenames)) {
  datalist[[i]] <- readxl::read_xlsx(path = allFilenames[i], sheet = "mySheet")
}
```

You want to load RData from a package you can use

```
ds <- data(package = "myPackage")
datalist <- list()
for (i in 1:length(ds$results[, 3])) {
  eval(parse(text = paste0("datalist[[", i, "]] <- myPackage::", ds$results[i, 3])))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by @dcarlson, you could extract the names of all datasets in your package and give them back as list to the `data()` function as argument `list`. However this solution only returns a promise for each dataset and not the actual dataset.

```
my_package <- "datasets"
name_of_all_datasets <- data.frame(data(package = my_package)$results)$Item
data(list = name_of_all_datasets, package = my_package)
```

Comment: "and not the actual dataset" that is a problem, but I have an idea how to solve the problem using `eval(parse(...))`.